# R: How to multiply list elements by a vector?

Tags: r, list

I want to multiply a list of matrices (with one row), like this:

```
lst <- list("111.2012"=matrix(c(1, 0, 6, NA, 1, 0),
                            nrow = 1, byrow = T),
          "112.2012"=matrix(c(6, 2, 2, 0, 3, NA),
                            nrow = 1, byrow = T))
```

with a vector like this (with the same length as each matrix):

```
vec <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
```

And expect this result:

```
$`111.2012`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    0   18   NA    2    0

$`112.2012`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    6    4    6    0    6   NA
```

I tried so far this:

```
mapply("*", lst, vec) 
Map("*", lst, vec)
```

Which gives my three times more numbers and the wrong ones. I also thought of using lapply within mapply to adress the list, but didn't know how to do it. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 10):

I believe you are looking for `lapply()`, since you are using a list `lapply( lst, FUN= function(x) x*vec)`

For more information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega).

Hope that helps!

```
lapply(lst,FUN= function(x) x*vec) ## My old clunky way

lapply(lst, "*" , vec) ## As informed by Richard Scriven (Thanks!)

$`111.2012`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    0   18   NA    2    0

$`112.2012`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    6    4    6    0    6   NA
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Map/mapply` works by applying the function to corresponding elements of the input variabless. For a `list` of length 2, we have 2 elements i.e. `lst[[1]]` and `lst[[2]]` and for a `vector` of length 6, it will be 6.  So, this creates an inequality.  In order to rectify this, we place the vector in a `list` (by wrapping with `list`), so that it gets recycled to the length of the 'lst' and will be used as a whole for each element in the 'lst'.

```
Map("*", lst, list(vec))
#$`111.2012`
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    0   18   NA    2    0

#$`112.2012`
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    6    4    6    0    6   NA
```